# How can I return a successful message using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, postman

I want to return a successful message when I create a new user: (It work perfectly, but there's no message)

My PostController:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@Valid @RequestBody CarroDTO objDto){
    Carro obj = service.fromDTO(objDto);
    obj = service.insert(obj);
    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(obj.getId()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
}
```

My CarroDTO:

public class CarroDTO implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;
private String model;
private String marca;
private String ano;


public CarroDTO() {
    
}
public CarroDTO(Carro obj) {
    id = obj.getId();
    model = obj.getModel();
    marca = obj.getMarca();
    ano = obj.getAno();
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}
public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}
public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}
public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}
public String getAno() {
    return ano;
}
public void setAno(String ano) {
    this.ano = ano;
}
```

}

The service:

```
public Carro fromDTO(CarroDTO objDto) {
    return new Carro(objDto.getId(), objDto.getMarca(), objDto.getModel(), objDto.getAno( ));
}
```

In postman: [image]

Comment: Usually, a simple `200 HTTP OK` status code is enough, you don't need a message. But, when influencing entities in such a way that the client cannot predict what's happened, it's often good to return at least the ID of all influenced objects or even the full representations of the objects. How you do that in spring boot I do not know.

Comment: What are the headers in the response. --- *FYI:* The response is not supposed to have a body at all, so I don't know where that `1` is coming from, so try viewing the *Raw* response, in case the prettyfier is obscuring things.

Answer (score 1):

Your ResponseEntity is void, so nothing is required for the body   .
You can change it to a String  or a wildcard and attache a Body to your ResponseEntity.

ResponseEntity<?> Or ResponseEntity

#### example

```
ResponseEntity.ok().body(msg)
```